# WMI gives "Parameter is incorrect" error for two computers out of 15

Tags: vb.net-2010, wmic

I'm developing a tool in VB.net 2010 which connects to remote PC and gets files from few locations. It works well with 13 PC out of 15. Only 2 PCs having problem.
When i try to connect with the following code

`Dim sobjSWbemLocator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.IWbemLocator")
                Dim sobjWMIService = sobjSWbemLocator.ConnectServer("<PC_Name>", "root\cimv2", "<UserName>", "Password")`

It throws error "Parameter is incorrect". But i checked with other credentials, the error is same. If i give invalid user name, then it throws "Access is denied". 
My assumption is, the WMI in remote PC is causing this issue. But i have no clue where to fix it. Please give some suggestions to try.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `set` instead of `dim`? `SWbemLocator` instead of `IWbemLocator`?

Comment: .net is not allowing me to 'set'. It says, "Set and let no longer supported" (Am i missing something here)
Tried SWbemLocator but same error "Parameter is incorrect". :(